# How to set input value returned from API in AsyncCreatableSelect?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-select

I was wondering if I can set an input value for the input field of AsyncCreatableSelect if the API is returning these inputs [like in the screenshot below]

[image: 1]

```
                         <Grid item xs={12}>
                            <InputLabel shrink={true} htmlFor="tag">Tag</InputLabel>
                            <AsyncCreatableSelect autoFocus fullWidth value={values.tag} id="tag" name="tag"
                                isLoading={false}
                                isMulti
                                onChange={handleTagChange}
                                placeholder="Tags"
                                cacheOptions
                                defaultOptions
                                onCreateOption={createTag}
                                loadOptions={promiseOptions}
                            />
                        </Grid>
```